# Is there a "sensible" limit to WordPress Categories?

Tags: categories

I need to create 1,500 categories to a WordPress install.

Some posts will have 150 of those categories.

Is that crazy/ doable/ or "no problem" at all?

PS I don't plan on showing (looping) the categories to save time and resources on the frontend...

Comment: It sounds like you should use tags instead of categories for this. However I don't think there are any limit to how many categories a post can have and I don't think there would be any problem adding a post to 150 categories if this really is what you would like to do.

Comment: Thanks @Cyclonecode but I am already using Tags for an entirely other purpose...

Comment: Can you use a custom non-hierarchial taxonomy (tag) then? It's doable but the issue lies in how you're going to query them later?